# Use Maven-Plugin in Gradle

Tags: maven-assembly-plugin

I need a zip in which all tests and dependency jar will be zipped.
In maven we need to add below plugin in pom.xml and run mvn package command which will give me zip file in target folder.

maven-jar-plugin
maven-dependency-plugin
maven-assembly-plugin

Now I need to do this same in gradle project.How can I do above task in gradle?